# Failed opening required 'redirect:/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I moved my site from local to the server and the rewrite rules in my .htaccess were not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ index.php?p=2
</IfModule>
```

That is what I have in my .htaccess.

But I am sure .htaccess is recognized by the server ( I tested by putting some garbage in .htaccess - I got server error).

To further diagnose the problem, I modified my .htaccess like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ index.php?p=2
RewriteRule contact-us$ index.php?p=2
RewriteRule ^contact-us index.php?p=2
RewriteRule contact-us index.php?p=2
</IfModule>
```

Now, I am getting a strange error while visiting my site.com/contact-us

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'redirect:/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: That error is from PHP. I do not know what your script does, but check for file permissions (e.g. session files location, compiled templates/cached files etc). **But in general:** to check if rewrite works -- do a temp redirect, so that URL will change in browser as well, e.g. `RewriteRule ^contact-us$ index.php?p=2 [R=302,L]`

Comment: can you open http://yourhostname/index.php?p=2 directly? it seems tom me like there's no index.php in that directory where the .htaccess file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is somehow adding .php to my URL automatically. ( I think because of the AddHandler)

I have a `contact-us.php`, but I want to route `contact-us` to `index.php?p=2`. Since Apache is adding .php and checking if contact-us.php exists, it is not matching the `contact-us` route. So I renamed my file to `php-contact-us.php` and kept the route and my URL same. So the redirect works as expected now.